# Error applying special sympy functions with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, math, sympy, symbolic-math

Im trying to create a graph with numerical solutions of a magnetic field. The object is a solenoid.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
from scipy.integrate import quad_vec

t, x, y, z = smp.symbols("t x y z")

l = smp.Matrix([0.5 * smp.cos(t), 
                0.5 * smp.sin(t), 
                (t / (600 * smp.pi)) * smp.Heaviside(t - 1) * smp.Heaviside(t)])

r = smp.Matrix([x, y, z])
sep = r-l

integrand = smp.diff(l, t).cross(sep) / sep.norm()**3

dBxdt = smp.lambdify([t, x, y, z], integrand[0])
dBydt = smp.lambdify([t, x, y, z], integrand[1])
dBzdt = smp.lambdify([t, x, y, z], integrand[2])

def B(x, y, z):
    return np.array([quad_vec(dBxdt, 0, 2*np.pi, args=(x, y, z))[0],
                     quad_vec(dBydt, 0, 2*np.pi, args=(x, y, z))[0],
                     quad_vec(dBzdt, 0, 2*np.pi, args=(x, y, z))[0]])

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 20)
xv, yv, zv = np.meshgrid(x, x, x)

B_field = B(xv, yv, zv)
Bx, By, Bz = B_field
```

```
File <lambdifygenerated-8>:2, in _lambdifygenerated(t, x, y, z)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(t, x, y, z):
----> 2     return (-(y - 0.5*sin(t))*((1/600)*t*DiracDelta(t)*select([less(t, 1),equal(t, 1),True], [0,1/2,1], default=nan)/pi + (1/600)*t*DiracDelta(t - 1)*select([less(t, 0),equal(t, 0),True], [0,1/2,1], default=nan)/pi + (1/600)*select([less(t, 0),equal(t, 0),True], [0,1/2,1], default=nan)*select([less(t, 1),equal(t, 1),True], [0,1/2,1], default=nan)/pi) + 0.5*(-1/600*t*select([less(t, 0),equal(t, 0),True], [0,1/2,1], default=nan)*select([less(t, 1),equal(t, 1),True], [0,1/2,1], default=nan)/pi + z)*cos(t))/(abs(x - 0.5*cos(t))**2 + abs(y - 0.5*sin(t))**2 + abs((1/600)*t*select([less(t, 0),equal(t, 0),True], [0,1/2,1], default=nan)*select([less(t, 1),equal(t, 1),True], [0,1/2,1], default=nan)/pi - z)**2)**(3/2)

NameError: name 'DiracDelta' is not defined
```

Comment: yep, `lambdify` doesn't know how to translate `DiracDelta` (and many other functions) into numpy terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use [SymPy Plotting Backends](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

The first thing we can do is to rewrite `Heaviside` with `Piecewise`. This will create visually longer expressions, but they will evaluate much faster with `mpmath`.

I'm going to create a 3D streamline plot. Evaluation with NumPy is going to fail because it doesn't know what `DiracDelta` is. But evaluation with mpmath will succeed. However, mpmath doesn't support vectorized operations, so evaluation will be slow.

```py
from spb import *

# rewrite integrand's Heaviside with Piecewise
a = smp.Integral(integrand[0].rewrite(smp.Piecewise), (t, 0, 2*smp.pi))
b = smp.Integral(integrand[1].rewrite(smp.Piecewise), (t, 0, 2*smp.pi))
c = smp.Integral(integrand[2].rewrite(smp.Piecewise), (t, 0, 2*smp.pi))

graphics(
    vector_field_3d(
        a, b, c, (x, -2, 2), (y, -2, 2), (z, -2, 2),

        # `a, b, c` are complicated expressions, whose
        # latex representation would make the backend fail.
        # let's set an easier label
        label="a", 

        # number of discretization points on each direction.
        # Remember you are discretizing a volume, so you will have
        # n^3 evaluation points. The higher this number the slower
        # the evaluation.
        n=10,

        # evaluates the expressions with mpmath.
        # mpmath appears to be able to deal with `DiracDelta`, and
        # it is usually faster than SymPy at evaluating an expression.
        # however, it is much much slower than NumPy, hence n must be
        # kept low
        modules="mpmath",

        # visualize streamlines (True) or quivers (False)
        streamlines=True,
        stream_kw={
            # request random starting locations for the streamlines
            "starts": True
        }
    ),

    # use the plotting library K3D
    backend=KB, 
)
```

[image]

It looks like a mess, but with K3D you can quickly add clipping planes (click K3D-Panel -> Controls -> Clipping Planes -> Add New).

[image]

If you look closely, all streamlines appears to lay on some meridian plane. So, we can chose a 2D plane, for example the plane XZ (y=0):

```py
a = smp.Integral(integrand[0].rewrite(smp.Piecewise).subs(y, 0), (t, 0, 2*smp.pi))
b = smp.Integral(integrand[1].rewrite(smp.Piecewise).subs(y, 0), (t, 0, 2*smp.pi))
c = smp.Integral(integrand[2].rewrite(smp.Piecewise).subs(y, 0), (t, 0, 2*smp.pi))

from spb import *
graphics(
    vector_field_2d(
        a, c, (x, -2, 2), (z, -2, 2),
        label="Magnitude",
        modules="mpmath",
        
        # do not visualize a contour plot with magnitude of the
        # vector field, as it evaluate over 100^2 points, which
        # is too slow for this complicated expression
        scalar=False,
        
        # visualize streamlines (True) or quivers (False)
        streamlines=True,
        
        # streamlines benefit from higher number of discretization points
        n=30
    ),
    backend=MB, aspect="equal", grid=False,
    xlabel="x", ylabel="z", title=r"$\vec{B}(x, 0, z)$"
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with this function is that its value is infinite, in sympy when DiracDelta(0) returns 'DiracDelta(0)'. Thinking that the Gaussian approximation exists, I solved this problem by looking at how "integrand" behaves mathematically. Whenever "t" in "integrad" is 0 this function is overridden, so I removed it by hand.